# How to block Wi-Fi on tablet via interface without possibility to restore

Tags: wi-fi, tablet, internet

Is it possible and how to block Wi-Fi on a tablet via its Android's interface without possibility to restore Wi-Fi back via the interface?

So that I would be able to restore Wi-Fi only with root permissions or by means of reinstalling Android

Maybe type a password somewhere and forget it. Or something else, I don't know...

Comment: You should explain in detail what you want to do and why. Often such questions like yours can be solved using a different approach you don't had in mind when qrit.ing the question. Therefore the "why" is very important...

Comment: @Robert I understand you. But in this specific case WHY I need to block Wi-Fi is exclusively my personal matter and has nothing to do with this website. I just need to know HOW to block it

Answer (score 1):

There are **apps** that will block Wi-Fi, meant for parental control.

However, the easiest way to do it is on the **router**.  You can easily set up a rule on the router to block that **MAC address**.  The proviso is that the tablet is not set up for random MACs.

Comment: Related: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-mac-randomization-behavior

Comment: Rohit Gupta, the router is not a way as there may be another Wi-Fi hotspot nearby (not mine) a tablet can connect to. Regarding the apps: I meant without possibility to restore Wi-Fi via Android's interface including installed apps. Is it impossible to restore the connection back with the same apps?